# Accessing dates in PHP beyond 2038

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp, year2038

I am of of the understanding that due to the nature that PHP represents dates using milliseconds, you cannot represent dates past 2038.  I have a problem where I want to calculate dates far in the future.  Thousands of years away.

Obviously I cannot use the php date function to represent this date because of the limit, however, I have something on my side...  All I want to do is store the year, month and day.  I do not care for the hour, minute, seconds and milliseconds.

Am I correct in thinking that without including this additional information I should be able to calculate a lot further into the future because I am willing to discard a lot of information.  Is this any library that currently does this?  If not does any have any advice on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Using timestamps is only a problem on 32-bit setups. PHP running on 64-bit machines can represent dates beyond 2038.

Comment: As if PHP 5.6.15 64-bit Windows build uses 32-bit timestamps. Also, the strtotime() function returns 32-bit signed timestamp (returns negative values for dates after 2038) and the date() function understands only 32-bit signed timestamps.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can alternatively use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) class, which internally represents the time components independently. Thus it is not susceptible to the 2038 limitation (unless you use ::getTimestamp).

Comment: Thank you it looks like this is going to work for me because I will not need to use any timestamps, superb :)

Comment: Is there a way to get the timestamp back out without it being truncated?

Comment: This is only a very limited solution! What if I want to use filemtime() to get the date of a file after 2038 ?

Comment: @Elmue `filemtime()` uses the underlying timespec struct/integer size of the OS. In the case of 64-bit OSes, it returns dates larger than 2038.

Comment: Completely correct. But if I have to use a 64 bit OS I don't need your answer anymore. The DateTime class is useless if I want to work with file times. So the correct answer is the one from alex: If you want to use dates after 2038 you MUST use a 64 bit OS. The DateTime class is only a very limited workaround. This is just what I wrote in my comment!

Comment: The x64 builds of PHP 7 support native 64-bit integers, LFS, 64-bit memory_limit and much more.

Answer (score 9):

You *could* use a 64bit platform.

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18.

[Source](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Find out your platform is 64bit with `var_dump(PHP_INT_SIZE === 8)`.  If `TRUE`, your system is 64 bit.

Comment: Another option to test this is: echo 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF; which should print 9223372036854775807 if integer is 64 bit.

Comment: Nevertheless what a shame is PHP! Why are the PHP folks not able to compile a 32 bit version that uses variables of 64 bit? This can be done with a few compiler switches.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has introduced [Datetime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class in version 5.2 to solve this problem. But you still must be in 64-bit OS.

Comment: If this is true, then PHP is completely misdesigned. PHP internally is programmed in C++ which easily allows to use 64 bit variables EVEN on a 32 bit platform! (see ULONGLONG)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that PHP doesn't allow you to handle dates > 2038, natively. However there are libraries such as [this one](http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/adodb_date_library) that take advantage of the fact that floating points are 64 bit, thus allowing you to bypass this issue if need be. (All under the assumption that you are using a 32 bit system... if you are using 64 bit, you are fine).

Answer (score 1):

Forget Windows! Even if you're running Apache 64-Bit over Windows 64-Bit!

```
$timestamp = strtotime('22-09-2508');
var_dump ($timestamp);
// returns bool false using WAMP 64-Bit over Windows 64 Bit
```

If you need to calculate timestamps, use a 64 bit system (not Windows):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('22-09-2508');
var_dump ($timestamp);
// returns int 17000496000 using a LAMP Server
```

You can run a LAMP Server using VMWare over your Windows and most likely your final host server will use this 64-Bit service as well.

In other words:

```
if (intval("9223372036854775807")==9223372036854775807) {
  // 64-bit
} else {
  // 32-bit
}
```

Got it ?

*Note: time() and getTimestamp() both work ok in 64bit environment (linux) after year 2038 ..*

Comment: As if PHP 5.6.15 64-bit Windows build uses 32-bit timestamps. Also, the strtotime() function returns 32-bit signed timestamp (returns negative values for dates after 2038) and the date() function understands only 32-bit signed timestamps.

Comment: It is COMPLETE nonsense to say "Forget Windows". As if this would depend on the operating system! PHP internally is C++ code. On Windows you can EASILY use 64 bit variables EVEN on a 32 bit platform. Visual Studio header files define 64 bit types as ULONGLONG or LONGLONG since decades. It is the fault of PHP folks who make a LOT of design errors. The correct answer would be: "Forget PHP". It is a shame that PHP still uses 32 bit signed integers. Why does PHP not offer 64 bit variables from THE FIRST DAY, like C++, C# and others do? It is a severe design error in PHP, not in Windows!

Answer (score -1):

This question is one of the very first problem being discovered in PHP lately.

I think is best to get the users' date from `DateTimeImmutable` and store it as a variable char in the database.

When retrieving the dates you can make a simple function to display dates in a format that you love.

E.g. date can be:

```
$date = "4069-03-27 00:00:00";
// store it as a variable char in the database
```

You can make a function to compare, subtract and also do a lot more with it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).