# how to find day of the week of future date like 12-25-2049

Tags: php, datetime

I have tried the following code to find the day in a week.

```
<?php
$day = date('l', strtotime( $date));
?>
```

When I enter the date "12-25-2049", it says "Wednesday" but it should be "Saturday".
But when I enter the date "11-11-2014" or "2015" it gives the correct day of the week.

Why is the first date not working as expected?

Comment: <?php $day = date('l', strtotime( $date));?>

Comment: please post the actual code that you used. I do know that PHP tries to interpret dates. Your example looks like it can be parsed uniquely. Still, it would be nice to see what you actually did? PHP `DateTime` should do something sensible with that value. Did you try 'createFromFormat' ?

Comment: @Amit you are giving it the wrong format for 2049

Comment: The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. - http://de1.php.net/strtotime --- also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319710/accessing-dates-in-php-beyond-2038

Answer (score 1):

Provide the correct date format

```
  $date = '25-12-2049';
  echo date('l', strtotime($date)); // satureday
```

**Update**

as @showdev suggested

```
$date = '12/25/2049'; //if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed
echo date('l', strtotime($date)); // satureday
```

Comment: For reference, "if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed." [PHP: strtotime notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes)

Comment: @showdev He was using dash(-) and he was providing the wrong format

Comment: Yes, I agree. I provided the documented explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP timestamp is limited to 2038, it must be the cause of your problem.

Here are more informations : [Why do timestamps have a limit to 2038?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879173/why-do-timestamps-have-a-limit-to-2038)

Comment: wider than PHP it's the unix timestamp issue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem