# PHP getTimestamp not working when adding 100 years

Tags: php, datetime

I need to build a calculator which adds 100years and out puts as timestamp. but i can't get it to work over X number or years?

***WORKS

```
$date = new DateTime('1980-02-15');
$date->modify('+15 year');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

***DOESNT WORK

```
$date = new DateTime('1980-02-15');
$date->modify('+105 year');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: What is the error? What does it mean "it doesnt work"??

Comment: https://3v4l.org/aoRvT Works for me.

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit system? You'll have trouble with timestamps past 2038-01-19 if so.

Comment: OP seems correct. not working:- https://eval.in/861528. It seems integer limit passed-out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879173/why-do-timestamps-have-a-limit-to-2038