# What exactly is considered to be a Timestamp? Does it have standard formats?

Tags: date, datetime, time, timestamp

What exactly is considered to be a timestamp?

Does it have standard formats? Is it language specific? How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timestamp is basically a numeric value of seconds, between 1st January 1970, to January 19, 2038 (aprox.). That is simply because the integer is "maxed out" at 2147483648 seconds.
You can read [more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879173/why-do-timestamps-have-a-limit-to-2038).

As for the format, a lot of languages ( I assume all, but am not sure) allow you to set your own format, like dd/mm/yyyy, mm/dd/yyyy etc.

Here's an example in PHP. This gets the current date, and outputs it in your desired format.

```
$date=date("Y/m/d");
echo $date;
```

The output will be **2019/11/20**

Not every language is the same tho, so this may vary from language to language.
Hope it helps!

[This is also worth checking out](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)!