# javascript date above year 2035 crashes app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

when i select date above 2035 in react-native date-time picker and apply any javascript date method to it, react native app crashes. pls i need help on this

e.g

```js
let dates = new Date("2060-08-25T23:15:30.000Z").toLocaleDateString();
```

Comment: I found a similar opened issue on GitHub: https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/219

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette That issue mentions a [question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879173/why-do-timestamps-have-a-limit-to-2038) as the "answer". Why not use that as a dupe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do timestamps have a limit to 2038?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879173/why-do-timestamps-have-a-limit-to-2038)

Comment: lol@Andreas, Because I didn't read it completely...

Comment: @ Louys Patrice Bessette  so does it mean there is no workaround to this?. if there is can u possibly help me out? thanks for the quick reply

Comment: The only way one can help is you update your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).