# How to decrement a date in a textbox?

Tags: php

How could I decrement the date in the text box by 1 day? The value of the dateschedule is 2016-04-02. The output should be 2016-04-01 because I want to decrement it by 1 day. I tried this code:

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"]))
        {
        $dateschedule=security($_POST["dateschedule"]);
    echo    $new_time4 = date($dateschedule, strtotime('-1 day'));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the format of your date function is not going to work as you expect.. see [php date manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

and as also posted on [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651263/subtract-1-day-with-php), you may use this:

```
$new_time4 = date('Y-m-d',(strtotime( '-1 day' , strtotime( $_POST["dateschedule"]))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by using DateTime.

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-04-02');
$date->modify('-1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

//Output: 2016-04-01
```

https://3v4l.org/mD2GR

I find this alot more readable, you can easily see what you are doing and you can change your output easily with the format funciton.