# penultimate day of month in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

So far with

```
strtotime('last day of this month');
```

gives me the last day (31), but I want the penultimate (30), and I've tried with:

```
strtotime('-1 day','last day of this month');
```

Also with strtotime('last day of this month') - strtotime('1 day'); and other things. Always results in (formatted with date()) 31-dec-1969.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. **strtotime()** expects parameter 2 to be an integer in case of subtracting a time span from a date. So you need to

1. convert the last day of the month to an integer timestamp value using `strtotime('last day of this month')`
2. Then subtract a day from it by doing `strtotime('-1 day', $valueFromStep1)`

Hence doing

`strtotime('-1 day',strtotime('last day of this month'))`

Gives the expected answer

Here is a similar question to the one you have asked: [Subtract 1 day with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651263/subtract-1-day-with-php)

**strtotime reference:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: In case you find this answer useful. Do feel free to accept it :) Happy PHPing!

Comment: Okay. Meanwhile I'll try to make this answer more useful for people out there :)