# How to -1 day from the endDate

Tags: php

```
<p>Closing on <span>{{ $event->endDate->format('d/m/Y') }}</span></p>
```

Now my current result is Closing on 13/1/2017.

The result I request for is Closing on 12/1/2017.

how to -1 day from it?

Comment: It looks like a date-time object, but who really knows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract 1 day with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651263/subtract-1-day-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime('-1 day', strtotime(date('13-01-2017'))));
```

Use strtotime, it support this -1day notation.

or datetime oop way

```
echo (new DateTime('13-01-2017'))->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('d-m-Y') ;
```

In your case,

```
echo (new DateTime($event->endDate->format('d-m-Y')))->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('d/m/Y') ;
```

Comment: In other words: `echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime('-1 day', strtotime(date($event->endDate->format('d/m/Y')))));` But if this is a datetime object... there are far simpler ways..

Comment: added this option. Well, i don't see it's simpler.

Comment: The problem is that the question contains a template language which is  unclear. And what I mean with simpler is seconds, 3600 of them.

Comment: I got you. just assume it gives output as '13-01-2017'

Comment: `echo (new Datetime('13-01-2017'))->modify("-1 day")` ha!

Comment: Sorry, forgot the extra `()` for the new object.

Comment: So in essence, `$event->endDate->modify('-1 day')->format('d/m/Y')`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) function.

```
// Initial date
echo $event->endDate->format('d/m/Y'); // 13/1/2017

// Modify the date    
$oneDayAgo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 
           strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($event->endDate->format('d/m/Y'))));
echo $oneDayAgo; // 12/1/2017
```