# code to find new year for a given criteria

Tags: php, calendar

I came to a see a interesting post that i am trying to write a code for that

> "Hello,On which of the two days of the week, Saturday or Sunday, does New Year’s Day fall often"

Reference :http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080731110435AAlyxd4

> i have found solution
>
> Calendar repeats itself every 400 years, but because 2100 etc are not leap years, the distribution is not even.It turns out that Sunday and Tuesday and Friday have the most occurrences of Jan 1 - 58 every 400 years.
>
> ```
>    Monday - 56
>    Tuesday - 58
>    Wednesday - 57
>    Thursday - 57
>    Friday - 58
>    Saturday – 56
>    Sunday - 58
> ```

But I am not getting, how I can replicate this in PHP?

For this who think that i have not try ans try to downloadvote my question. I have already test the code.

```
function DayOfNewYearsDay($beginYear,$endYear)
{
for($i=$beginYear;$i<$endYear;$i++)
{
$day = date("l", mktime(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, $i));
if(isset ($days[$day]))
$days[$day]++;
else
$days[$day]=1;
}
return $days;
}

echo  print_r(DayOfNewYearsDay(2000, 2400));
```

But i am not getting 58 Sunday as answer

Any Idea ?

Comment: Well, a good start would be to link us to the post so we know what's going on...

Comment: its a yahoo Question.http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080731110435AAlyxd4

Comment: Someone try here code also. but it did;t work http://www.abdohoo.com/discussion/15/what-the-two-days-of-the-week-saturday-or-sunday-does-new-year-day-fall-more-often-prove-via-php/p1#_

Comment: My main motive here is to replicate this in PHP. :(

Comment: What did you to get it?

Comment: Please use formating standarts, such as padding of code inside {} bracket, or your code is veryhardtoread.

Comment: Your problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319710/accessing-dates-in-php-beyond-2038

Comment: I get that php 5.2 has new class "DateTime" and how we will use than that for here code. i haven't use this class yet now :(

Comment: What answer did you get? I tried your code, it returns 58 for Sunday.

Comment: Even i try echo print_r(DayOfNewYearsDay(1901 , 2038));, it is print only Array ( [Thursday] => 21 [Wednesday] => 20 [Friday] => 19 [Sunday] => 19 [Monday] => 20 [Tuesday] => 19 [Saturday] => 19 ) :(

Comment: Array ( [Thursday] => 316 [Wednesday] => 15 [Friday] => 15 [Sunday] => 14 [Monday] => 14 [Tuesday] => 13 [Saturday] => 13 ) .It return this when i have use echo print_r(DayOfNewYearsDay(1600, 2000)

Comment: BTW, if you are checking new years days from 2000-01-01 up to and including 2400-10-01, you actually check 401 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DateTime object to get around the php limitation in mktime:

```
function DayOfNewYearsDay ($beginYear, $endYear)
{
    for ($i = $beginYear; $i < $endYear; $i++) {
        $date = new DateTime;
        $date->setDate($i, 1, 1);
        $day = $date->format('l');
        if (isset ($days[$day]))
            $days[$day]++;
        else
            $days[$day] = 1;
    }

    return $days;
}
```

http://codepad.org/iGou6dk4

Answer (score 1):

I dont want to spoon feed you. So giving a simple algorithm

1. Create an array A
2. For number range 1600 to 2000

   1. Create a datetime object of date "Number-01-01".
   2. Get the week day of datetime
   3. increment A[weekday] by `1`
3. Just print the array.

Comment: ,I have already write the alogo.But i am expecting answer as Sunday 58. Since which is corrct answer. Thts why i have posted question here

Comment: That result will come if you run the program in year range `1600`-`2000`. And its stated in my answer already.

Comment: Array ( [Thursday] => 316 [Wednesday] => 15 [Friday] => 15 [Sunday] => 14 [Monday] => 14 [Tuesday] => 13 [Saturday] => 13 ) .It return this when i have use echo  print_r(DayOfNewYearsDay(1600, 2000)

Comment: calendar is bugged and works only from 1901 to 2038, see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40346

Comment: Even i try echo  print_r(DayOfNewYearsDay(1901 , 2038));, it is print only Array ( [Thursday] => 21 [Wednesday] => 20 [Friday] => 19 [Sunday] => 19 [Monday] => 20 [Tuesday] => 19 [Saturday] => 19 )  :(

Comment: @kajacx That is only true for 32-bit versions of PHP. You can use any 4-digit year if you are using a 64-bit version (I'm not sure if it also requires a 64-bit OS).

Comment: @jyoti You should use DateTime. I used DateTime and [it works](https://eval.in/33628).