# PHP IF statement with Date not returning False

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to learn a little bit of php and can not understand why the 2 second IF is executing here. I have a variable $theDate set to accept a European date 4th May 2010.

```
$theDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("04-05-2010"));
echo "$theDate<br />";

if($theDate > "02-05-2010")
{
 echo "Greater than!<br />";
}

if($theDate > "02-05-2011")
{
 echo "Why am I showing<br />";
}

echo "Endof";
```

I just want to use IFs for now, no IF-Else etc. But why is the 2nd IF executing when $theDate is NOT greater than 02-05-2011,

thanks in advance,

Joe

Comment: What .... what what .. who told you this comparison ?

Comment: Because date() returns a string. You are comparing two string. Not dates.

Comment: I found it on StackExchange, somewhere. What is the correct method to compare a Date?

Comment: I have submitted simple answer to your question, also please check this for future reference http://www.phptherightway.com/ it may help you with many how-to-do things.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Thanks scx - I will try that solution and take a look at your link - cheers, Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember its 2014. Why not use [DateTime object and do why not do it right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/#date_and_time)??

```
$raw = '04-05-2010';
$theDate= \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $raw);
$raw2 = '02-05-2010';
$anotherDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $raw2);

echo 'theDatedate: ' . $theDate->format('m/d/Y') . "<br>";
echo 'anotherDate date: ' . $anotherDate ->format('m/d/Y') . "<br>";

if ($theDate > $anotherDate ) {
    echo "Greater than!<br />";
}
```

If you are learning php please check [this resource, is worth reading.](http://www.phptherightway.com/#date_and_time)

Answer (score 2):

To compare dates as string just use the UTC format YYYY-MM-DD. If you want to compare it as integer you have to convert it to seconds or compare  starting with the year and then with the month and so on---

Answer (score 1):

It uses string comparison. Thus it first looks at the first character, if that is greater than, `true` is returned. If less, `false` is returned. If equal, move to the next character.

You can solve this by formatting the string in reverse: `Y-m-d`. Or by using a built-in operator:

```
if($time > strtotime($text))
```

where `$time` is specified in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

> You are comparing strings. Convert Date to seconds and then compare,
>   working one for all formats etc.

```
$theDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("04-05-2010"));
echo "$theDate<br />";
if(strtotime($theDate) > strtotime("02-05-2010"))
{
 echo "Greater than!<br />";
}
if(strtotime($theDate) > strtotime("02-05-2011"))
{
 echo "Why am I showing<br />";
}
echo "Endof";
```

Comment: Note: This will only work with dates until 2038 - that's already a reachable range today. I suggest using the DateTime class instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319710/accessing-dates-in-php-beyond-2038