# PHP 64bit on Windows and strtotime above 2038 not work

Tags: php, windows, apache, 64-bit, unix-timestamp

I'm aware of the year 2038 problem in PHP because of the 32bit limitation of integer values. I know that i need a 64bit system to make it working.
Well, i've done so, i installed `Apache 2.4.12 Win64` and `PHP Version 5.6.6RC1 - Thread Safe 64bit` for windows. I'm also on windows 7 64bit.
And my problem is, strtotime still cannot handle dates higher than year 2038.
Maybe there's a struggle in my head but i can't find the problem. I asking explicitly for `strtotime`, i know the solution of `DateTime` which is working, but i have old projects that uses lot of `strtotime`. Also i cannot get rid of the windows platform, it's just so here in our company :(

```
var_dump(strtotime("2038-11-01"));
// output: bool(false)
```

**Edit1:** I've tested php 7.0.0dev and here it works. Seems like i must wait for PHP7 to get proper 64bit on Windows. Luckily, 7.0.0dev seems right now pretty stable for me.

**Edit2**: With PHP7 the problem doesn't exist anymore. It is not recommended anymore to use any 5.x branch.

Here is my phpinfo output
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing dates in PHP beyond 2038](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319710/accessing-dates-in-php-beyond-2038)

Comment: @Rizier123 It's not a duplicate because i already use a 64bit system as suggested in this topic. Also i want to know why strotime is not working, DateTime is not alternative for me here.

Comment: Did you read all answers in the possible duplicate?! Even the last one? Your problem is the second tag in your question

Comment: Hm, yes right now i've seen it but that not answer the question why this not work in windows. It just says it's not working here, but why, i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the latest master snapshot, to grab here http://windows.php.net/downloads/snaps/master/ . Generally - it doesn't matter whether your windows is 64-bit itself. With PHP5 the underlying API is 32-bit for many things including time and integers. PHP7 (the master builds I've linked) have true 64-bit support.

Thanks.