# PHP 64bit or 32bit?

Tags: php

I have the need to run some old code in PHP 5.6.40, latest version of 5.6. I have downloaded and installed the NTS X64 version of PHP and it is running fine.

However, if I execute PHP_INT_SIZE I get a value of 4 and not a value of 8, which tells me that I am running 32bit!

If I execute the same code under 7.4 or 8, I get 8, or 64bit.

Can someone please explain why I am getting PHP_INT_SIZE to report 4, when I have installed the x64 version of PHP 5.6.40?

Thanks,
Adri

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27865372/5947043 - and see the comment below it too

Comment: Probable duplicate of [PHP\_INT\_SIZE returns 4 But my Operating System Is 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865340/php-int-size-returns-4-but-my-operating-system-is-64-bit)

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have also found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580255/php-64bit-on-windows-and-strtotime-above-2038-not-work