# Correct way to store MySQL date after year 2037

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime, year2038

I am trying to store in MySQL a **date()** field a successive date to the year **2037**.

For example: `2065-12-01`

Problem is that the field is returning: `1969-12-31`

What is the correct way to record these values on DB? Should I use *VARCHAR*?

I compute the `date` field's value like this:

```
 $future_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$number_years_to_add years"));
```

Comment: A `DATE` type works fine here, are you running some antique MySQL version or something? Also, how exactly are you setting it?

Comment: How are you trying to store it? We can't see any sample code...

Comment: I Use  5.5.16 version

Comment: can you show your table date ??@HidDencum

Comment: Ok, this is how add date, i think problem is here:
$future_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$number_years_to_add years"));

Comment: change your column type for **DATE to Varchar** @HidDencum

Comment: When you add information to your question, it's best to edit the question.

Comment: Are on 64-bit PHP? If not, maybe you should upgrade first.

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2012620/9675332

Answer (score 5):

You probably use a timestamp field to store the dates and not a datetime field.

See mysql documentation on [datetime data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), specifically:

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. **The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'**.
>
> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. **The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'**.
>
> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and
>   time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of **'1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to
>   '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC**.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you're using the php `date` and `strtotime` stuff on a 32-bit platform.  Those functions turn into a pumpkin, like Cinderella's carriage, at [03:14:07 UTC on 19 January 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

You may wish to check out the new php [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) class, or upgrade to a 64-bit php implementation.

Also, read this.  [Accessing dates in PHP beyond 2038](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319710/accessing-dates-in-php-beyond-2038)

*(Thanks for catching this problem with 22 years of advance notice. Others will not.)*