# MySQL Service not starting when i change my date to 2037 or above

Tags: mysql, xampp

I don't know whats going on but when i change my current date to year 2037 or above MySQL in xampp wont start.
I am getting this when i try to start after setting date. Please note the last line in log. it stuck at "Attempting to start MySQL app..."

[image]

Comment: Did you also check the actual logs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33802653/2310830

Comment: Yess same. The issue is not only with me also with my client. he told me that its not starting after 2037. then i tried it not started on my end too

Comment: I also looked at that but. My Case is different a little bit because my MySQL is not even starting. how can i fix it with that?

Comment: Question: Windows or *nix? And are you 32bit or 64bit

Comment: Another read https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116055/how-to-start-mysql-after-the-year-2038

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: 64bit Windows 10 i used 64bit Xampp too.