# PHP strotime - String to Date - wrong date result

Tags: php, date

When I try to convert very high dates, such as 2045-01-01, I get another date:

> date("Ymd", strtotime("2045-02-15"));

I obtain a wrong date

> 19700101

but when

> date("Ymd", strtotime("2017-02-15"));

I have the good date

> 20170215

I don't understand why? Someone just explain to me what's going on?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319710/accessing-dates-in-php-beyond-2038

Comment: A: you've been hit with the 2038 bug. Edit: `$date = date("Ymd", strtotime("2037-02-15"));` this works, and this fails `$date = date("Ymd", strtotime("2038-02-15"));`

Comment: `11111111111111111111111111111111` becomes `00000000000000000000000000000000` -> 1970-01-01

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a unixtimestamp problem (=> https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unixzeit#/media/File:Year_2038_problem.gif), better:

```
date_parse("2006-12-12 10:00:00");
date_parse_from_format ( 'Ymd' , "2017-02-15" );
```

or

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', "2017-02-15");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```