# Why can't I add more than 7400 days to date in php?

Tags: php, date

When I am using `date()` function do add certain number of days to date is working with:

```
date('d.m.Y', strtotime("+".round(5000)." days"))
```

but it is not working with:

```
date('d.m.Y', strtotime("+".round(7500)." days"))
```

Is there anyone who knows why, and how do I fix this?

Comment: What mean you can't add? https://3v4l.org/uWPof

Comment: You using 32bit system? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319710/accessing-dates-in-php-beyond-2038

Comment: btw date and strtotime should be switched out for datetime. Only noobs use them functions ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely it is due to the [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) combined with a 32bit version of PHP.

You can check your php version by checking the value of the `PHP_INT_SIZE` constant (which will be 4 for x32 and 8 for x64).

Any dates after january 19'th 2038 overflows the 32-bit signed integer used for the Unix timestamp.

5000 days from today is March 27, 2032

7500 days from today is January 30, 2039

Using a 64bit version of PHP you should be good until year 292277026596.